# How to find a specific "term/text" in the HTML tags using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, livefyre

This is my code:
I am passing URL stored in a list and for each URL I parse it using 'html.parser'. I am looking for the term "livefyre"

```
for page in links:
    req = requests.get(page, headers=hdr)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.find('div', attrs={"id" : "livefyre-comments"}):
        print(len(link.get_text()))
```

This only outputs the div elements matching the specific "id" : "livefyre-comments". I want to search for all/any occurrences of "livefyre" anywhere on the HTML page. Please help.

Comment: You can do that without BeautifulSoup, using `req.text.find('livefyre')`.  It would be up to you to decide how much context you need around the citations.

Comment: It is returning a list of numbers when I print it. Could you please explain the results? @Tim Roberts

Comment: `req.text` is just a string.  The string `.find` function returns the character index where the string was found, or -1 if it was not found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tag[attr*='val']` CSS selector, which checks if `val` is a substring of the value attached to the attribute `attr` for tags `tag`. This would match the following elements, for example:

- `<tag attr="value">`
- `<tag attr="values">`
- `<tag attr="valuables">`
- `<tag attr="invalid">`

So, using this CSS selector, you can modify the code using the `bs4.BeautifulSoup.select()` method:

```py
for page in links:
    req = requests.get(page, headers=hdr)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
    for elem in soup.select("div[id*='livefyre']"):
        print(len(elem.getText())
```